# Using a scanner loop across classes (Java)

Tags: java, debugging, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use a scanner loop as a method in my input class, in my main method. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Blackjack.Input.getBet(Input.java:27)
at Blackjack.BlackJackGame.main(BlackJackGame.java:23)
```

Here is the loop (this loop is in a separate class) :

```
    public int getBet(int cash) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = sc.nextInt();
        while (bet > cash) {
            outputter.cannotBet();
            outputter.askBet();
            bet=sc.nextInt();
        }
    return bet;
}
```

And here is where I call it in my main method:

```
user.setBet(input.getBet(user.getCash()));
```

Basically, the user should not be allowed to bet more money than he or she has, and while the bet is more than the cash he or she has, it should loop and ask the user to re-enter a number. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `outputter` assigned a value?

Comment: outputter is a separate class that just prints lines to the console

Comment: Which line is Input.java:27 ?

Comment: Hard to understnd your program. We may need more code. I guess you should use do { }while () loop... very rarely used one

Comment: outputter.cannotBet();  is input.java.27

Comment: @bobs_007 which code should i add? I can add my main method and the input and output classes, if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it more simpler. Please try this.
I removed other unknown methods from my code.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = 0;
    do {
          bet=sc.nextInt();
    } while (bet > cash);

    return bet;
```

Say if you pass cash as 100, then you typed 200 as bet, it will ask input again. If bet is 20, then condition false and return the value. Hope it helps you.

Comment: the only thing is that cash>0 so wouldn't it skip over the loop in the first place? should i just initialize bet as a really large number?

Comment: According to your program, bet is coming from System.in means console. So you can what ever value you want.... 10000 or something. If you want really huge value make it "long"

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this

```
 public int getBet(int cash) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int bet = sc.nextInt();
    while (bet > cash) {
        outputter.cannotBet();
        outputter.askBet();
        bet=sc.nextInt();
    }
return bet;
}
```

with this

```
 public int getBet(int cash) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int bet = 0;//or you could put this as a global variable, but its considered "bad practise"
    while (bet > cash) {
        bet = sc.nextInt();
        outputter.cannotBet();
        outputter.askBet();
        continue;
    }
return bet;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: why do you need  continue; there??

Comment: it resets the while loop and u need it because u restarted your entire method with a variable set in the method<< doesnt work. hence, the continue command reseting the loop rather than your entire method

Comment: if i do this, where should i initialize int bet?

Comment: it won't allow me to do the while loop without int bet